# Are btrfs advantages negated with over-the-top encryption?

Tags: filesystems, encryption, btrfs

Are the benefits of btrfs lost if one uses encryptFS on top?   What advantages (over ext4) of btrfs remain intact with encryptFS?  If I want to have the full benefits of btrfs with encryption, is LUKS the way to go?

Comment: This is opinion based in the same way as “Dose `ls` list files?“. I.E not opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use LUKS under btrfs.

EncryptFS on top would negate;

- Transparent compression
- Data deduplication
- Copy-on-write (  because COW is on partial file hunks and  encryptFS would re-encrypt the whole file )

Comment: Then again, the point of encryption is to hide the data, including if some files/blocks are identical. So it's not just about "negating" advantages, but of conflicting goals.